# How to find the GPS coordinates of a point on the road the vehicle will reach after traveling for X minutes using heremap api?

Tags: here-api

How to find the GPS coordinates of a point on the road the vehicle will reach after traveling for X minutes using heremap api? The point has to be on the road. I tried using isoline. However, it gives me a set of points and not necessarily on the road.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Maneuver#getStartTime()](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-routing-maneuver.html#topic-apiref__getstarttime-void) API to find the maneuver and associated road that the user is currently on? You can interpolate the length of the element in the maneuver to get a more accurate measurement.